# couchDB sorting complex key

Tags: couchdb

I have a couchDB database which has several different document "types" which all relate to a main "type".

In the common blog / post example, the main type is the blog post, and the others are comments (though there are 3 different types of comments.

All of the types have a date on them, however, I wish to sort blog posts by date, but return all of the data from the comments as well. I can write an emit which produces keys like so:

```
[date, postID, docTypeNumber]
```

where docTypeNumber is 1 for post and > 1 for the different comment document types.

e.g:

```
["2013-03-01", 101, 1]
[null, 101, 2]
[null, 101, 2]
[null, 101, 3]
["2013-03-02", 101, 1]
[null, 102, 2]
[null, 102, 3]
```

Of course, If I emit this, all the nulls get sorted together. Is there a way to ignore the nulls, and group them by the seccond item in the array, but sort them by the first if it is not null?

Or, do I have to get all the documents to record the post date in order for sort to work?

I do not want to use lists, they are way too slow and I'm dealing with a potentially large data set.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using conditionals in your map function.

```
if(date != null) {
  emit([date, postID, docTypeNumber]);
}
else {
  emit([postID, docTypeNumber]);
}
```

I don't know if you want your array length to be variable or not. If not, you could add the sort variable first. The following snippet could work since date and postID presumably never have the same values.

```
if(date != null) {
  sortValue = date;
}
else {
  sortValue = postID;
}
emit(sortValue, date, postID, docTypeNumber);
```

Update: I thought about this a little more. In general, I make my views based on queries I want to perform. So I ask myself, *what do I need to query?* It seems that in your case, you *might* have two distinct queries here. If so, I suggest having two different views. There is a performance penalty to pay since you would run two views instead of one, but I doubt it is perceivable to the user. And it might take up more disk space. The benefit for you would be clearer and more explicit code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I'm missing something here. With the first option, doesn't it sort by the first item in the array? If not, how does it know to sort by the postID? I'm really excited by your answer, if you're right couchDB just got way better for me.

Comment: I think I'd prefer the 2nd form over the 1st. However, the first would still work. Your view collation for posts would effectively be `[101, x]`. Your view collation for dates would be something along the lines of `[2013-03-07, x, x]`. And you could also query by date and post `[2012-03-07, 101, x]`. Please note that both views depend on the fact that postID and date never have the same value.

Comment: Neither options works when I query the view. It sorts from the front of the array, so it's compares the post's postID with the comment's date. All of your post ids are listed, then all of your posts. Is there an option that you can pass when you query the view to make it different?

Comment: I see. I thought you were trying to do something a little different and query the view using keys. Now I see you want the entire view sorted by the post's date. I see two options: 1) store the post date in comments; or 2) follow Marcin's suggestion of making the post ID meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to sort all the data (both the post and the comments) with post's date. Since in your design comment document does not contain post date (just comment date) it is difficult with the view collation pattern. I suggest changing the database design to have blog post ID meaningful and contain the date, eg. concatenated date with author id. This way if you emit `[doc._id, doc.type]` from the post and `[doc.post, doc.type]` from the comment document you will have post and comments grouped and sorted by date.